# getResource() not finding file?

Tags: java, file, io, directory

When trying to load the file in Eclipse the file loads just fine, however when I package the project into a .JAR file using jar-splice it seems that the application can no longer locate its resource files.

[Here's the error thrown when the application is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9PbL.png)

And here is the method that loads files:

```
public static File loadFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    InputStream stream;

    stream = FileUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
    System.out.println("Stream = " + stream); //Debug purposes


    File file = new File(FileUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path).getFile());
    if (!file.exists())
    {
        System.err.println("Path: " + FileUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path).getPath()); //Also debug purposes
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }

    return file;
}
```

Using those two System.out.printlns it's clear that the application can't find the file based on that path, but if you look at the picture that path is exactly where the file it's looking for is located. I am so confused as this has never happened before, and the path it's saying it can't find the file at is exactly where it is. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: `getResource` does not search files. A resource is not a file.

Comment: Do not post a link to a picture of a stack trace.  Copy and paste the entire stack trace into your question, indented by four spaces so it appears as a code-formatted blocked.

Comment: The picture was more or less to demonstrate that the images are in the same location that the stack trace says it isn't in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is the method that files

Here is the method that neither does nor can load resources as Files. It is impossible. Resources are not files and do not live in the file system. You must redesign it to return either a URL or an InputStream, and as you can get both directly from a Class or ClassLoader you don't actually need the method at all.

Comment: You are correct, it's just not possible. Right now I'm writing a gaming library in conjunction with LWJGL, which will mostly use resources from jar files, so I redesigned the library to use InputStreams instead of Files. Works exactly the same and it actually works after compiling!